# why are my forms not valid (both forms.Form and ModelForm), and why is it not saving data to data base?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, django-forms

**views.py**

my view contains two form, userform which I created with forms.Form and snippetform which I
created with ModelForm.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Snippetform, Userform
from .models import User, Snippet
from django import forms 

# Create your views here.

def user(request):
    form = Userform()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Userform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            fname = form.cleaned_data["fname"]
            lname = form.cleaned_data["lname"]
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            password2 = form.cleaned_data["password2"]

            new_user = User.objects.create(username,fname,lname,email,password,password2)
            new_user.save()

    return render(request,'my_app/user.html',{'form':form})


def snippet(request):
    form = Snippetform()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Snippetform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors.as_data())



    return render(request,'my_app/snippet.html',{'form':form})



def thanks(request):

    return render(request,'my_app/thanks.html',)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms 
from . models import Snippet

class Userform(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    fname = forms.CharField(label="First name")
    lname = forms.CharField(label="Last name")
    email = forms.EmailField(label="E-mail")
    password = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    password2 = forms.IntegerField(label="Confirm password",required=False)

class Snippetform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ("name","body")
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    password = models.IntegerField()
    password2 = models.IntegerField()

class Snippet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=150)
```

**urls.py**

```
from  django.urls import path
from . import views 

#registered namespace for my app name which is "my_app"
app_name = 'my_app'


urlpatterns = [
    path('user/',views.user,name='user'),
    path('snippet/',views.snippet,name='snippet'),
    path('thanks/',views.thanks,name='thanks'),
]
```

**snippet.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to Snippet view!!</h1>

<form action="{% url 'my_app:thanks' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

   </body>
</html>
```

**user.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to the User view!</h1>

<form action="{% url 'my_app:thanks' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

**thank.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to the Thank you view!</h1>

<h1>Thank you for filling this form</h1>

   </body>
</html>
```

**admin.py**

#I even registered my models in admin.py to view my data objects from there but it did not
save any data, and I also checked on shell too, but it did not save any.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import User,Snippet
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(Snippet)
```

Comment: You can easily figure out what's wrong by printing:

`print(form.errors)`
`print(form.non_field_errors())`

Comment: Yes, I've tried printing out errors but nothings is showing on my terminal. Even when I try to print(valid) if form.is_valid(): still it doesn't display valid on my terminal.

Comment: If `form.is_valid()`, there won't be any errors. Where is your else block? Where are you checking for when your form DOES have errors? (In the first one) Did you set up your auth_user_model in settings?

Comment: Please, what do you mean by auth_user_model? I've checked it up on google but I don't understand the things I've been seeing. Can you please, explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a link to the docs for creating a custom user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django

Comment: Why are you saving the user after creating it?

Comment: Thank you very much?.... Isn't there need to save it? After calling the model new user = User.objects.create(username, fname...).. new_user.save()...and also form.save() in Modelform. Isn't it correct this way?

Comment: Create user object, then save()..isn't it correct that way?

Comment: No, it isn't. You would only want to call `.save()` after creating a model like this: `User(username,fname,lname,email,password,password2)`. Not after `.create()`, but this isn't the main issue. Create an else block, and check if the form has `print(form.errors) print(form.non_field_errors())`.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I can see the errors on the terminal now. The snippet form is valid but the Userform is invalid. Please, what do I do to stop seeing "bound method Base form.non_field_errors"?

Comment: You forgot the `()` parenthesis. It should tell you what the errors are.

Comment: Thank you very much, bro.. It runs perfectly now... I really appreciate your help..